# React Native Error- can't find variable:NameFields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am defining one of my components as NameFields using the typical module.exports synatx but within the same file on compilation I receive an error saying it can't find the NameFields variable as in here :[image]

The file can be found in full here:
https://gist.github.com/jqed-xuereb/ad5f1facc15ddcdff758c04a07b1dae8

Thanks in advance,
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created class `AccountFields` and exporting `NameFields`

replace this line:

```
module.exports = AccountFields
```

or change name of class

Comment: Thanks very much ! I've been looking at this for so long I guess i couldn't see it

Comment: Welcome, you can accept as an answer if found helpful, so others can know it is answered